# Inno Setup: add GUI to connect to SQL

Tags: sql-server, connection, inno-setup

Complete Inno Setup and Pascal newbie here. I want to package a single `.sql` file inside a `setup.exe`.

The setup will be available for download so I can't embed any connection strings within the setup project. The setup basically installs an .NET CLR assembly (dll as hex stream) into the supplied SQL server database by running a simple `.sql` script

I've seen the other posts on here about connecting to an SQL server but none address my issue of a hardcoded connection string or replicating/implementing the generic Data Connection Dialog that pops up in all MS apps for making a DB connection

Ideally the creation of the connection string should be handled via the Data Connection Dialog that MS have released the code for http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection but have no idea how to link this to pop up during the install.

If not possible without (too much) effort then another option would be to have a custom cut down version of the dialog screen within Inno Setup with just the server name\path text box.

A checkbox to specify whether to use Windows or SQL server authentication (username/pass text boxes gets enabled when SQL authentication is selected)

At which point the connection is attempted and a drop down with the available databases appears.

I can get the server\instance text box working but have no idea how to implement the Windows authentication\SQL authentication combo box and subsequent actions

Tips?

edit: Thanks TLama, the MS supplied connection dialog UI seems like a no go then. I've gotten the 'appearance' aspect right using the Inno Setup form wizard, but some of the functionality still baffles me:

I have no idea how to

- enable/disable the `lblUser`, `lblPassword`, `txtUsername`, `txtPassword` when `chkSQLAuth.selected` is true/false.
- enable the `lstDatabase` combo box and label once there is content in the `txtServer` textbox.
- populate the `lstDatabase` combo box using the credentials specified (connect to server and execute `"SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1 ORDER BY name"`) on click of the `lstDatabase`.
- Then enable the Next button when a database is selected.

I think once that's done I should be able to figure out how to execute my SQL script against the selected database!

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=test
AppVersion=1.0
LicenseFile=C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Script Studio\License.rtf
CreateAppDir=False
UsePreviousGroup=False
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
Uninstallable=no

[Files]
Source: "C:\Install Assembly.sql"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy


[CustomMessages]
CustomForm_Caption=Connect to Database Server
CustomForm_Description=Enter the information required to connect to the database server
CustomForm_lblServer_Caption0=Server name:
CustomForm_lblAuthType_Caption0=Log on credentials
CustomForm_lblUser_Caption0=User name:
CustomForm_lblPassword_Caption0=Password:
CustomForm_lblDatabase_Caption0=Database:
CustomForm_chkSQLAuth_Caption0=Use SQL Server Authentication
CustomForm_chkWindowsAuth_Caption0=Use Windows Authentication

[Code]
var
  lblServer: TLabel;
  lblAuthType: TLabel;
  lblUser: TLabel;
  lblPassword: TLabel;
  lblDatabase: TLabel;
  chkSQLAuth: TRadioButton;
  txtServer: TEdit;
  chkWindowsAuth: TRadioButton;
  txtUsername: TEdit;
  txtPassword: TPasswordEdit;
  lstDatabase: TComboBox;

 var
  Page: TWizardPage;
{ CustomForm_Activate }

procedure CustomForm_Activate(Page: TWizardPage);
begin
  // enter code here...
end;

{ CustomForm_ShouldSkipPage }

function CustomForm_ShouldSkipPage(Page: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
end;

{ CustomForm_BackButtonClick }

function CustomForm_BackButtonClick(Page: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

{ CustomForm_NextkButtonClick }

function CustomForm_NextButtonClick(Page: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

{ CustomForm_CancelButtonClick }

procedure CustomForm_CancelButtonClick(Page: TWizardPage; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
  // enter code here...
end;

{ CustomForm_CreatePage }

function CustomForm_CreatePage(PreviousPageId: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Page := CreateCustomPage(
    PreviousPageId,
    ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_Caption}'),
    ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_Description}')
  );

  { lblServer }
  lblServer := TLabel.Create(Page);
  with lblServer do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_lblServer_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(24);
    Top := ScaleY(8);
    Width := ScaleX(68);
    Height := ScaleY(13);
  end;

  { txtServer }
  txtServer := TEdit.Create(Page);
  with txtServer do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Left := ScaleX(112);
    Top := ScaleY(8);
    Width := ScaleX(273);
    Height := ScaleY(21);
    TabOrder := 0;
  end;


  { lblAuthType }
  lblAuthType := TLabel.Create(Page);
  with lblAuthType do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_lblAuthType_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(24);
    Top := ScaleY(48);
    Width := ScaleX(87);
    Height := ScaleY(13);
  end;


  { chkWindowsAuth }
  chkWindowsAuth := TRadioButton.Create(Page);
  with chkWindowsAuth do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_chkWindowsAuth_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(32);
    Top := ScaleY(64);
    Width := ScaleX(177);
    Height := ScaleY(17);
    Checked := True;
    TabOrder := 1;
    TabStop := True;
  end;

  { chkSQLAuth }
  chkSQLAuth := TRadioButton.Create(Page);
  with chkSQLAuth do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_chkSQLAuth_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(32);
    Top := ScaleY(84);
    Width := ScaleX(185);
    Height := ScaleY(17);
    TabOrder := 2;
  end;


  { lblUser }
  lblUser := TLabel.Create(Page);
  with lblUser do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_lblUser_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(56);
    Top := ScaleY(104);
    Width := ScaleX(58);
    Height := ScaleY(13);
    Enabled := False;
  end;

  { lblPassword }
  lblPassword := TLabel.Create(Page);
  with lblPassword do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_lblPassword_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(56);
    Top := ScaleY(128);
    Width := ScaleX(53);
    Height := ScaleY(13);
    Enabled := False;
  end;

  { txtUsername }
  txtUsername := TEdit.Create(Page);
  with txtUsername do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Left := ScaleX(120);
    Top := ScaleY(104);
    Width := ScaleX(241);
    Height := ScaleY(21);
    Enabled := False;
    TabOrder := 3;
  end;

  { txtPassword }
  txtPassword := TPasswordEdit.Create(Page);
  with txtPassword do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Left := ScaleX(120);
    Top := ScaleY(128);
    Width := ScaleX(241);
    Height := ScaleY(21);
    Enabled := False;
    TabOrder := 4;
  end;

   { lblDatabase }
  lblDatabase := TLabel.Create(Page);
  with lblDatabase do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_lblDatabase_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(56);
    Top := ScaleY(168);
    Width := ScaleX(53);
    Height := ScaleY(13);
  end;

  { lstDatabase }
  lstDatabase := TComboBox.Create(Page);
  with lstDatabase do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Left := ScaleX(120);
    Top := ScaleY(168);
    Width := ScaleX(145);
    Height := ScaleY(21);
    TabOrder := 5;
  end;

  with Page do
  begin
    OnActivate := @CustomForm_Activate;
    OnShouldSkipPage := @CustomForm_ShouldSkipPage;
    OnBackButtonClick := @CustomForm_BackButtonClick;
    OnNextButtonClick := @CustomForm_NextButtonClick;
    OnCancelButtonClick := @CustomForm_CancelButtonClick;
  end;

  Result := Page.ID;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = Page.ID then
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := False;  
end;

{ CustomForm_InitializeWizard }

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  CustomForm_CreatePage(wpWelcome);
end;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got it working. Here it is in case someone else wants similar functionality. Just change the link to the license and the `.sql` file references

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=test
AppVersion=1.0
LicenseFile=C:\setup demo\License.rtf
CreateAppDir=False
UsePreviousGroup=False
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
Uninstallable=no

[Files]
Source: "C:\setup demo\script 2008R2.sql"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "C:\setup demo\script 2012.sql"; Flags: dontcopy

[CustomMessages]
CustomForm_Caption=Connect to Database Server
CustomForm_Description=Enter the information required to connect to the database server
CustomForm_lblServer_Caption0=Server name:
CustomForm_lblAuthType_Caption0=Log on credentials
CustomForm_lblUser_Caption0=User name:
CustomForm_lblPassword_Caption0=Password:
CustomForm_lblDatabase_Caption0=Database:
CustomForm_lblVersion_Caption0=SQL Version:
CustomForm_chkSQLAuth_Caption0=Use SQL Server Authentication
CustomForm_chkWindowsAuth_Caption0=Use Windows Authentication
CustomForm_lstVersion_Line0=2008 R2
CustomForm_lstVersion_Line1=2012

[Code]
const
  adCmdUnspecified = $FFFFFFFF;
  adCmdUnknown = $00000008;
  adCmdText = $00000001;
  adCmdTable = $00000002;
  adCmdStoredProc = $00000004;
  adCmdFile = $00000100;
  adCmdTableDirect = $00000200;
  adOptionUnspecified = $FFFFFFFF;
  adAsyncExecute = $00000010;
  adAsyncFetch = $00000020;
  adAsyncFetchNonBlocking = $00000040;
  adExecuteNoRecords = $00000080;
  adExecuteStream = $00000400;
  adExecuteRecord = $00000800;

var
  lblVersion: TLabel;
  lstVersion: TComboBox;
  lblServer: TLabel;
  lblAuthType: TLabel;
  lblUser: TLabel;
  lblPassword: TLabel;
  lblDatabase: TLabel;
  chkSQLAuth: TRadioButton;
  txtServer: TEdit;
  chkWindowsAuth: TRadioButton;
  txtUsername: TEdit;
  txtPassword: TPasswordEdit;
  lstDatabase: TComboBox;
  bIsNextEnabled: Boolean;

 var
  Page: TWizardPage;

{ Used to generate error code by sql script errors }
procedure ExitProcess(exitCode:integer);
  external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';

{ Version drop down defaults to blank. Enable server textbox once a version is selected. This forces user to select the version first. }
Procedure VersionOnChange (Sender: TObject);
begin                            
  lblServer.Enabled := True;
  txtServer.Enabled := True;
end;

{ enable/disable child text boxes & functions when text has been entered into Server textbox. Makes no sense to populate child items unless a value exists for server. }
Procedure ServerOnChange (Sender: TObject);
begin                            
  lstDatabase.Items.Clear;
  lstDatabase.Text := '';
  bIsNextEnabled := False;
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := bIsNextEnabled;
  if Length(txtServer.Text) > 0 then
  begin
    lblAuthType.Enabled := True;
    lblDatabase.Enabled := True;
    lstDatabase.Enabled := True;
    chkWindowsAuth.Enabled := True;
    chkSQLAuth.Enabled := True;
  end
  else
  begin
    lblAuthType.Enabled := False;
    lblDatabase.Enabled := False;
    lstDatabase.Enabled := False; 
    chkWindowsAuth.Enabled := False;
    chkSQLAuth.Enabled := False;
  end
end;

{ enable/disable user/pass text boxes depending on selected auth type. A user/pass is only required for SQL Auth }
procedure  AuthOnChange (Sender: TObject);
begin
  if chkSQLAuth.Checked then
  begin
    lblUser.Enabled := true;
    lblPassword.Enabled := true;
    txtUsername.Enabled := true;
    txtPassword.Enabled := true;
  end
  Else
  begin
    lblUser.Enabled := false;
    lblPassword.Enabled := false;
    txtUsername.Enabled := false;
    txtPassword.Enabled := false;
  end
end;

{ Enable next button once a database name has been entered. }
Procedure DatabaseOnChange (Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Length(lstDatabase.Text) > 0) and (lstDatabase.Enabled) then
  begin
    bIsNextEnabled := True;
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := bIsNextEnabled;  
  end
  else
  begin
    bIsNextEnabled := False;
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := bIsNextEnabled;  
  end
end;

{ Retrieve a list of databases accessible on the server with the credentials specified. }
{ This list is shown in the database dropdown list }
procedure RetrieveDatabaseList(Sender: TObject);
var  
  ADOCommand: Variant;
  ADORecordset: Variant;
  ADOConnection: Variant;  
begin
  lstDatabase.Items.Clear;
  try
    { create the ADO connection object }
    ADOConnection := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');
    { build a connection string; for more information, search for ADO }
    { connection string on the Internet  }
    ADOConnection.ConnectionString := 
      'Provider=SQLOLEDB;' +               { provider }
      'Data Source=' + txtServer.Text + ';' +   { server name }
      'Application Name=' + '{#SetupSetting("AppName")}' + ' DB List;'
    if chkWindowsAuth.Checked then
      ADOConnection.ConnectionString := ADOConnection.ConnectionString +
      'Integrated Security=SSPI;'         { Windows Auth }
    else
      ADOConnection.ConnectionString := ADOConnection.ConnectionString +
      'User Id=' + txtUsername.Text + ';' +              { user name }
      'Password=' + txtPassword.Text + ';';                   { password }
    { open the connection by the assigned ConnectionString }
    ADOConnection.Open;
    try
      { create the ADO command object }
      ADOCommand := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Command');
      { assign the currently opened connection to ADO command object }
      ADOCommand.ActiveConnection := ADOConnection;
      { assign text of a command to be issued against a provider }
      ADOCommand.CommandText := 'SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1 ORDER BY name';
      { this property setting means, that you're going to execute the }
      { CommandText text command; it does the same, like if you would }
      { use only adCmdText flag in the Execute statement }
      ADOCommand.CommandType := adCmdText;
      { this will execute the command and return dataset }
      ADORecordset := ADOCommand.Execute;
      { get values from a dataset using 0 based indexed field access; }
      { notice, that you can't directly concatenate constant strings }
      { with Variant data values }
      while not ADORecordset.eof do 
      begin
       lstDatabase.Items.Add(ADORecordset.Fields(0));
       ADORecordset.MoveNext;
      end

    finally
      ADOConnection.Close;
    end;
  except
    MsgBox(GetExceptionMessage, mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;

{ Execute files specified in [files] section (hardcoded) against the user defined server.database }
procedure DeploySQL();
var  
  Script2008R2: AnsiString;  
  Script2012: AnsiString;    
  ADOCommand: Variant;
  ADOConnection: Variant;  
begin
{ extract required version of script }
  if lstVersion.Text='2008 R2' then
    ExtractTemporaryFile('Script 2008R2.sql')
  if lstVersion.Text='2012' then
    ExtractTemporaryFile('Script 2012.sql');

  try
    { create the ADO connection object }
    ADOConnection := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');
    { build a connection string; for more information, search for ADO }
    { connection string on the Internet }
    ADOConnection.ConnectionString := 
      'Provider=SQLOLEDB;' +               { provider }
      'Data Source=' + txtServer.Text + ';' +   { server name }
      'Initial Catalog=' + lstDatabase.Text + ';' +   { server name }
      'Application Name=' + '{#SetupSetting("AppName")}' + ' Execute SQL;' ;     
    if chkWindowsAuth.Checked then
      ADOConnection.ConnectionString := ADOConnection.ConnectionString +
      'Integrated Security=SSPI;'         { Windows Auth }
    else
      ADOConnection.ConnectionString := ADOConnection.ConnectionString +
      'User Id=' + txtUsername.Text + ';' +              { user name }
      'Password=' + txtPassword.Text + ';';                   { password }
    { open the connection by the assigned ConnectionString }
    ADOConnection.Open;
    try
      { create the ADO command object }
      ADOCommand := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Command');
      { assign the currently opened connection to ADO command object }
      ADOCommand.ActiveConnection := ADOConnection;
      { load a script from file into variable. Exclusive OR because both versions should never exist at the same time. }
        if (LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Script 2012.sql'), Script2012)) xor (LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Script 2008R2.sql'), Script2008R2))     then
      begin
        { assign text of a command to be issued against a provider. Append all 3 because one of the install assembly strings will always be empty. }
        ADOCommand.CommandText := Script2008R2 + Script2012;
        { this will execute the script; the adCmdText flag here means }
        { you're going to execute the CommandText text command, while }
        { the adExecuteNoRecords flag ensures no data row will be get }
        { from a provider, what should improve performance }
        ADOCommand.Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdText or adExecuteNoRecords);
      end
      else
      begin
        MsgBox('Installation files missing.', mbError, MB_OK);
        ExitProcess(7);
      end
    finally
      ADOConnection.Close;
    end;
  except
    MsgBox(GetExceptionMessage, mbError, MB_OK);
    ExitProcess(5);
  end;
end;

{ CustomForm_NextkButtonClick }
{ try to connect to supplied db. Dont need to catch errors/close conn on error because a failed connection is never opened. }
function CustomForm_NextButtonClick(Page: TWizardPage): Boolean;
var  
  ADOConnection: Variant;  
begin
    { create the ADO connection object }
    ADOConnection := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');
    { build a connection string; for more information, search for ADO }
    { connection string on the Internet }
    ADOConnection.ConnectionString := 
      'Provider=SQLOLEDB;' +               { provider }
      'Data Source=' + txtServer.Text + ';' +   { server name }
      'Initial Catalog=' + lstDatabase.Text + ';' +   { server name }
      'Application Name=' + '{#SetupSetting("AppName")}' + ' Execute SQL;' ;     
    if chkWindowsAuth.Checked then
      ADOConnection.ConnectionString := ADOConnection.ConnectionString +
      'Integrated Security=SSPI;'         { Windows Auth }
    else
      ADOConnection.ConnectionString := ADOConnection.ConnectionString +
      'User Id=' + txtUsername.Text + ';' +              { user name }
      'Password=' + txtPassword.Text + ';';                   { password }
    { open the connection by the assigned ConnectionString }
    ADOConnection.Open;
    Result := True;
end;

{ CustomForm_CreatePage }

function CustomForm_CreatePage(PreviousPageId: Integer): Integer;
begin

  Page := CreateCustomPage(
    PreviousPageId,
    ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_Caption}'),
    ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_Description}')
  );

  { lblVersion }
  lblVersion := TLabel.Create(Page);
  with lblVersion do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_lblVersion_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(24);
    Top := ScaleY(8);
    Width := ScaleX(61);
    Height := ScaleY(13);
  end;

  { lstVersion }
  lstVersion := TComboBox.Create(Page);
  with lstVersion do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Left := ScaleX(112);
    Top := ScaleY(8);
    Width := ScaleX(145);
    Height := ScaleY(21);
    Style := csDropDownList;
    DropDownCount := 2;
    TabOrder := 0;
    Items.Add(ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_lstVersion_Line0}'));
    Items.Add(ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_lstVersion_Line1}'));
    OnChange:= @VersionOnChange;

  end;

  { lblServer }
  lblServer := TLabel.Create(Page);
  with lblServer do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_lblServer_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(24);
    Top := ScaleY(32);
    Width := ScaleX(68);
    Height := ScaleY(13);
    Enabled := False;
  end;

  { txtServer }
  txtServer := TEdit.Create(Page);
  with txtServer do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Left := ScaleX(112);
    Top := ScaleY(32);
    Width := ScaleX(273);
    Height := ScaleY(21);
    TabOrder := 1;
    Enabled := False;
    OnChange := @ServerOnChange;
  end;

  { lblAuthType }
  lblAuthType := TLabel.Create(Page);
  with lblAuthType do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_lblAuthType_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(24);
    Top := ScaleY(72);
    Width := ScaleX(87);
    Height := ScaleY(13);
    Enabled := False;
  end;

  { chkWindowsAuth }
  chkWindowsAuth := TRadioButton.Create(Page);
  with chkWindowsAuth do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_chkWindowsAuth_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(32);
    Top := ScaleY(88);
    Width := ScaleX(177);
    Height := ScaleY(17);
    Checked := True;
    TabOrder := 2;
    TabStop := True;
    OnClick := @AuthOnChange;
    Enabled := False;
  end;

  { chkSQLAuth }
  chkSQLAuth := TRadioButton.Create(Page);
  with chkSQLAuth do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_chkSQLAuth_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(32);
    Top := ScaleY(108);
    Width := ScaleX(185);
    Height := ScaleY(17);
    TabOrder := 3;
    OnClick := @AuthOnChange;
    Enabled := False;
  end;

  { lblUser }
  lblUser := TLabel.Create(Page);
  with lblUser do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_lblUser_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(56);
    Top := ScaleY(128);
    Width := ScaleX(58);
    Height := ScaleY(13);
    Enabled := False;
  end;

  { lblPassword }
  lblPassword := TLabel.Create(Page);
  with lblPassword do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_lblPassword_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(56);
    Top := ScaleY(152);
    Width := ScaleX(53);
    Height := ScaleY(13);
    Enabled := False;
  end;

  { txtUsername }
  txtUsername := TEdit.Create(Page);
  with txtUsername do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Left := ScaleX(120);
    Top := ScaleY(128);
    Width := ScaleX(241);
    Height := ScaleY(21);
    Enabled := False;
    TabOrder := 4;
  end;

  { txtPassword }
  txtPassword := TPasswordEdit.Create(Page);
  with txtPassword do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Left := ScaleX(120);
    Top := ScaleY(152);
    Width := ScaleX(241);
    Height := ScaleY(21);
    Enabled := False;
    TabOrder := 5;
  end;

   { lblDatabase }
  lblDatabase := TLabel.Create(Page);
  with lblDatabase do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:CustomForm_lblDatabase_Caption0}');
    Left := ScaleX(56);
    Top := ScaleY(192);
    Width := ScaleX(53);
    Height := ScaleY(13);
    Enabled := False;
  end;

  { lstDatabase }
  lstDatabase := TComboBox.Create(Page);
  with lstDatabase do
  begin
    Parent := Page.Surface;
    Left := ScaleX(120);
    Top := ScaleY(192);
    Width := ScaleX(145);
    Height := ScaleY(21);
    Enabled := False;
    TabOrder := 6;    
    OnDropDown:= @RetrieveDatabaseList;
    OnChange:= @DatabaseOnChange;
  end;

  with Page do
  begin
    OnNextButtonClick := @CustomForm_NextButtonClick;
  end;

  Result := Page.ID;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
{ set initial status of next button. Should be disabled when page is first loaded, but should be enabled if user clicked back. }
  if CurPageID = Page.ID then
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := bIsNextEnabled;  
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
{ The preinstall step seems like the best time to do the actual install. The problem is that this is not a traditional install. Nothing is copied to the users' pc }
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
    DeploySQL;  
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  bIsNextEnabled := False;
  CustomForm_CreatePage(wpLicense);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your script. However, I can't see here what you've asked for, how do you show the DB source prompt dialog...

Comment: Maybe I wasn't too clear.

My qu didnt require the use of the ms conn dialog. I was after an installer page to dynamically generate a mssql conn string based on info entered that would have similar functionality (ie the auto population of the db dropdown) to that of the MS dialog. Whether that was achieved by using the code released by ms or rolling my own, whichever was easier.

I supplied the MS conn dialog info because i thought referencing that would be the easiest way to do it. But your 1st reply seemed to indicate that it wasn't as trivial as I'd initially hoped

Comment: It would be easy, but due to a lack of pointer support you must always fake the pointer type parameters of any import of interface or library function. And in this case I couldn't figure out how to fake that interface import.

Comment: Thank for the code, I ran into issue maybe you can help? microsoft ole db provider for sql server could not find stored procedure 'ÿþG'

Comment: This is really quite well done. I learned a few new things about Inno Setup as well.