# To check a remote SQL Server instance through inno setup

Tags: sql-server, inno-setup

I am trying to install JBoss server and deploy modules after configuring the SQL Credentials of a remote server (SQL Server name, Instance name and database name) through inno setup. The problem I am facing is, if the TCP/IP protocols is not enabled for the instance name in the remote server, the deployment fails during the Installation.

I need to check if the instance in remote SQL server is accessible from the Server where the JBoss is being installed. Please suggest a way.

P.S- I am using SQL Server Authentication to connect to the database.

Thanks in advance,

DeeJay.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762521/inno-setup-add-gui-to-connect-to-sql

Comment: Hi mirtheil, thanks for the reply. I tried the logic in the mentioned post. I am getting "adodb.connection provider cannot be found. it may not be properly installed" error. The SQL Server I am trying to connect is not my local but a remote machine. Is that throwing this error?

Comment: This is my connection string and the Server is SQL 2008 R2 . ADOConnection.ConnectionString := 
    'Provider=SQLNCLI10;' +               // provider
    'Server=TEST-DBS\SYSTEMS;' +   // server name
    'Database=TESTDB;' +       // default database
    'User Id=sa;' +                // user name
    'Password=pwd_Admin;';